# weblogic client certificate authentication per webapp module

Tags: servlets, ssl, web-applications, weblogic, client-certificates

i m using Weblogic 12c.

I would like to set up client certificate authentication (2-way SSL).  But i do not want to enforce client certificates for the whole server.  Basically, in our webapp most of the servlets should work with regular 1-way SSL (only server certificate is verified) without requiring client to provide the certificate.  But for one of the servlets client certificate authentication is needed.

I have set up similar thing for Glassfish using separate module for the servlet where 2-way SSL is required with web.xml deployment descriptor with login-config element indicating CLIENT-CERT authentication type.  I have also set up appropriate security constraints, roles and groups.

However this does not seem to work with Weblogic.  In the admin console under SSL i see "Two Way Client Cert Behavior" with 3 possible values: "client cert not requested", "requested but not enforced" and "requested and enforced".

If i set it to "not requested", client does not present any certificates at all (even though i have the same web.xml with CLIENT-CERT which works with Glassfish).  Setting to "requested and enforced" is not an option.  I also tried setting to "requested but not enforced" but that's also bad since the browser will ask for client certificate even for those pages where it is not needed (most of them) and we don't want that behavior.

Basically, it seems to me that Weblogic wants to enforce 2-way SSL for the whole server, but that's not what we need, we need it only for one webapp module.  Is it possible to do so?

Edit:
To clarify, i set up DefaultIdentityAsserter and created custom UserNameMapper to map client certificate to user name.  The problem however that if SSL setting (described above) is set to "not requested" then client certificate is not presented at all so the server cannot authenticate and i get 401 response.  And i can't use the other 2 SSL settings because then the server will ask for client certificate for all webpages and that's not what we want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create 2 Network Channels. See NetworkAccessPointMBean in WLST, or Environment/Servers/yourServer/Protocols/Channels in Admin Console.

- Channel 1: SSL enabled w/ one-way SSL, on a specific port
- Channel 2: SSL enabled w/ two-way SSL and client cert enforced, on a specific port

Then, access your web module on the appropriate port based on your client cert requirements.

This would only require one server.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.  Yeah this seems like a better option than using two servers.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific need, I would create 2 managed servers, setting up only one with 2 way SSL.
You can then deploy your applications on the appropriate managed server, depending if you want the 2 way SSL or not for it.

Then you need to add a reverse proxy in front of your WebLogic server in order to forward your user to the correct port, as you probably don't want to expose several ports.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yeah that would work, but i was hoping it could be done with just one server.  As far as i thought, having login-config element in web.xml (with CLIENT-CERT), would enable client certificates on per-app basis (or per app module).  I guess it is done via ssl renegotiation.  Not sure why it is not working with weblogic (i tried to speicfy -Dweblogic.security.ssl.enable.renegotiation=true option but it's not having any effect).

Comment: What happens if you remove the security contraints from the web.xml of your webapp that doesn't need any authentication? I believe you can, on a server configured for 2-way SSL, deploy an application with no security constraint... Not sure though, we gave up with client certificate, too complex as you can see :/

Comment: Actually the portion of our app that does not need client certificate does not have security constraints in their web.xml.  But if i specify 2-way SSL (by specifying "requested and enforced") on the server level, wouldn't it block everything because it would ask client for certificate when it doesn't have one?  I can try that of course.

Comment: Looks like having 2 managed servers is the only way for WebLogic.